# What loss function to use for Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy

train_labels = [68, 65, 67, 71, 69, 72, 75, 70, 85, 83, 88, 80, 80, 78, 79, 85, 88, 86, 92, 91, 91, 93, 93, 90, 96, 97, 100, 100]

train_samples = [[2, 1, 73],[4, 0.5, 65],[3, 1, 70],[6, 1, 75],[7, 0.5, 68],[9, 1, 72],[3, 5, 70],[2, 6, 65],[4, 5, 78],[8, 3, 75],[9, 2, 80],[9, 4, 69],[2, 2, 88],[3, 1, 85],[7, 1, 83],[9, 1, 87],[3, 5, 88],[2, 7, 84],[7, 3, 88],[9, 4, 85],[4, 1, 93],[3, 1, 95],[8, 1, 93], [9, 0.5, 92], [3, 5, 94], [2, 7, 96], [8, 4, 97], [7, 5, 94]]

train_labels = np.array(train_labels)
train_samples = np.array(train_samples)

model = Sequential([
  Dense(8, input_shape=(3,)),
  Dense(16),
  Dense(1)
])

print(model.summary())

model.compile(Adam(lr=0.0001), loss="????", metrics = ["accuracy"])

model.fit(train_samples, train_labels, validation_split = 0.1, batch_size=1, epochs=100, verbose = 2)
```

I'm trying to train a NN to predict a test mark based on hours slept, studied and current average in the course. I'm knew to NN's so I dont know what loss function to use. I've made a few NN's following tutorials and the accuracy is always around 95%, however, whatever loss function I use the accuracy is completely 0. Does anyone know if it's because I havent scaled my training set, or perhaps know the loss function to use? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The target that you're predicting exist in a continuous space (regression, instead of classification). The loss should be `"mse"` / `"mean_squared_error"`, and `metric = ["mse"]`.

For neural networks in general, it's advisable to normalize inputs into roughly `mean = 0` and `std = 1`. You can easily use scikit-learn's `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()` to achieve this.

The refactored code for your project would look something like this (tested on `tensorflow-cpu==1.9`, and `keras==2.2.2`):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
print(f"Tensorflow version: {tf.__version__}, Keras version: {keras.__version__}")

# data
train_labels = [68, 65, 67, 71, 69, 72, 75, 70, 85, 83, 88, 80, 80, 78, 79, 85, 88, 86, 92, 91, 91, 93, 93, 90, 96, 97, 100, 100]
train_samples = [[2, 1, 73],[4, 0.5, 65],[3, 1, 70],[6, 1, 75],[7, 0.5, 68],[9, 1, 72],[3, 5, 70],[2, 6, 65],[4, 5, 78],[8, 3, 75],[9, 2, 80],[9, 4, 69],[2, 2, 88],[3, 1, 85],[7, 1, 83],[9, 1, 87],[3, 5, 88],[2, 7, 84],[7, 3, 88],[9, 4, 85],[4, 1, 93],[3, 1, 95],[8, 1, 93], [9, 0.5, 92], [3, 5, 94], [2, 7, 96], [8, 4, 97], [7, 5, 94]]
train_labels = np.array(train_labels)
train_samples = np.array(train_samples)
# preprocessing (min-max or standard scaler is fine)
sc = StandardScaler()
train_samples_scaled = sc.fit_transform(train_samples)
print(f"Feature means before scaling: {train_samples.mean(axis=0)}, Feature means after scaling: {train_samples_scaled.mean(axis=0)}")

# neural network
model = Sequential([
  Dense(8, input_shape=(3,), activation='relu'),
  Dense(16, activation='relu'),
  Dense(1, activation='linear')
])
model.compile(Adam(lr=0.001), loss="mse", metrics = ["mse"])
# training
model.fit(train_samples_scaled, train_labels, validation_split = 0.1, batch_size=5, epochs=20, verbose = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I realized the loss function was dealing with classification so it wasn't compatible. I was looking for the right loss function to deal with regression. Thanks so much!

Comment: With `loss='mse'`, you don't need `metrics=['mse']` - it is redundant

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to predict a real number (the test mark), so you are dealing with a regression problem. You'll want to use `'mean_squared_error'` as a loss function, and track `mse` as a metric instead of accuracy.

Scaling your data (for instance between 0 and 1) is not strictly necessary, but it could help for your network to converge faster.